# Unable to find Groovy method when building Rhino with Intellij IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

While trying to build `https://github.com/mozilla/rhino`, I'm getting `Unable to find method` on `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods`.

so the build fails, and I'm unable to test Rhino built from source code, which is the goal.

#### Steps Taken

From the opening screen in IntelliJ, I check out the project:

[image: Intellij check out mozilla rhino from github]

I get this error `Unable to find method ''java.lang.String org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.capitalize(java.lang.String)''` right away, which I have not been able to fix:

[image: Unable to find Groovy method in IntelliJ build screen.]

There are two suggestions in the above `Re-download dependencies and sync project` and `Stop Gradle build processes`.  I have tried both with no improvement.

When I look at the `build.gradle` file, I see another suggestion `...configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources...`.  This also does not get past the missing Groovy method problem.

[image: Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources]

I have looked on S.O. for similar issues and tried various things under `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment`, but I realized I'm over my head since, conceptually, I'm not sure what I need and where that would go in the settings.

The command line items from the readme work as expected, but going back to `File > Build` still fails (added after tim_yates comment).

What changes are required to the IDE or to the build definitions to allow Mozilla Rhino to build properly?

Comment: Have you tried from the command line as per the readme?

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for mentioning the readme.  Yes, I did try the command line items from the readme on my first install attempt.  I wiped the first install, started again, and wrote-up the question, but neglected to include the steps in the readme.  I will improve the question.

Comment: Have you tried a version of IntelliJ that's less than 2 years old?

Comment: I hadn't, but did just now.  It works now.

Comment: As the issue is solemnly related to the ide and not at all to rhino, could you remove the rhino tag?

Comment: @Paul Rhino tag removed.  Building rhino error, but with an old version of intelli-j, so I agree, it doesn't need the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the latest (2022.1) version of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.  During the install, it asked if you wanted this IDE to be associated with **Groovy** file types, and I answered in the affirmative.

On this new install, the `Unable to find method` on `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethodserror` **did not** appear, so the problem was solved by upgrading the IDE (and also that required updating GIT).